# If no cycle in graph $G$ contains edge $e$, then every spanning tree of graph $G$ contains $e$.

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Let $G$ be a connected graph. Prove that the following statements are equivalent:

$(i)$  $G-e$ is not connected.

$(ii)$ No cycle in $G$ contains edge $e$.

$(iii)$ Every spanning tree of $G$ contains $e$

I did a contrapositive proof to show that $(i)$ $\implies$ $(ii)$

Suppose there is a cycle $C$ in $G$ that contains edge $e =(uv)$. This means that there exists a path $P'$ from vertices $u$ to $v$ not containing $e$. So $G-e$ is connected.

I want now to prove that $(ii)$ $\implies$ $(iii)$.
This is what I tried:

I supposed that $T$ is a spanning tree of $G$ NOT containing edge $e$. Then $T+e$ contains a cycle.

Is this enough to prove that $(ii)$ $\implies$ $(iii)$

What approach should I take, because I do not feel that this is the correct way.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Suppose $e$ connects nodes $u$ and $v$. If no cycle in $G$ contains edge $e$, it means that there is only one way to reach $v$ from $u$ - this edge. So, if this edge doesn't exist in any spanning tree, the tree will not be one connected component.

Comment: Regarding your argument that $T + e$ contains cycle - I think it's correct.

Comment: @Anita You've got it right. Give reasoning for the implication $(iii)\Rightarrow(i)$.

Comment: @kabenyuk I think the given argument doesn't address whether $e$ is an edge of the cycle which $T + e$ contains, which is important.

Comment: Thank you @MangoPizza for your helpful contribution.
I have one more question about spanning trees.

If every spanning tree of $G$ contains $e$ then every spanning tree of $G$ constructed by depth-first search contains $e$ (independently of the order in which we check in the FOR-loops in )

I understand that edge $e$ connects vertices $u$ and $v$ and it is the only way to reach $v$ from $u$, this means that in depth-first search we add edges and vertices succesively so we must have edge $e$ in the spanning tree to keep G connected.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: Thank you @kabenyuk for your helpful contribution.

Comment: Thank you @beanshadow for your helpful contribution.

Comment: @Anita Yes, indeed every spanning tree must contain edge $e$, regardless of how we construct it. If you construct it using DFS, then too, edge $e$ must be present. In fact, the edge $e$ is called a bridge, if you would like to learn more. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T$ is a spanning tree and $e\notin E(T)$, then $T+e$ contains a cycle.

This cycle necessarily contains $e$, because otherwise this cycle is contained in $T$, and this contradicts the fact that $T$ is a tree.

It seems to me that no further arguments are needed and the author of the question is absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

Like MangoPizza said in the comments,

Let $e = (uv)$. Then because $T$ is a spanning tree (and connected by definition of tree), there exists a path $(e_1, \dots, e_n)$ in $T$ connecting $u$ and $v$. Also, this path does not have $e$ as an edge. (Why?)

That means $(e_1, \dots ,e_n, e)$ is a cycle of $G$ containing $e$.